# Adding multiple users and their password to different servers

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to add multiple users (50) and set their password to 50 different servers from a jump host, so I wrote a while loop. Unfortunately it doesn't work as an answer is needed to before inputting the password on the remote server. I am not sure how to insert that in the code.
Any help would be appreciated

```
#! /bin/bash
cat file4 | while read user password ip sshp

do
echo $sshp | ssh root@$ip --stdin

useradd $user

echo $user:$password | chpasswd

done
```

Comment: Things that will make your life easier LDAP, pdsh, ansible. I would go for ansible, really!

Comment: I feel you bro, but when you don't have access to Ansible you still got to solve the problem. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Isn't setting up public key an option?

Comment: You can run mutiple commands by `echo pass | ssh root@ip -- bash -c 'foo; bar; tar', otherwise only the first argument the chpasswd is running locally

Comment: can you please explain the command for me. I don't really know what -- bash -c is  doing. Also you, are right. I kind of notice part of the command was running locally. How do I solve that?

Comment: bash -c command will run command, you use this when you need to run multiple commands like bash -c  'ls; pwd; hostname'

Comment: It will start a new bash and run the -c argument on it

Comment: What answer is needed to before inputting the password on the remote server?

Comment: yes, because the remote server is going to ask if the user "root" want to establish a connection

Answer (score 0):

You can set user password in non interactive mode via

```
#! /bin/bash
cat file4 | while read user password ip sshp
do
  echo $sshp | ssh root@$ip --stdin
  useradd $user
  echo "$password" | passwd --stdin $user
done
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel! My problem is at authentication level, not with adding the password. Thanks for your help!